# How to disable Wmaybe-uninitialized warning

Tags: c++, warnings

I want to disable "Wmaybe-uninitialized" warning.
I use omnet++ ( base on c++ ) to simulate my project.
Is there anyway to disable this warning ?
I also found the following code , but it doesn't work.

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wmaybe-uninitialized"
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Comment: Disable everywhere? Maybe `-Wno-maybe-uninitialized`.

Comment: @juanchopanza yes everywhere, but it's useless too

Comment: @farshadsoheily You probably shouldn't do so. Fix the warnings instead.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the flag `-Wno-maybe-uninitialized` works, but should be used with care. See the thread [GCC -Wuninitialized / -Wmaybe-uninitialized issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132898/gcc-wuninitialized-wmaybe-uninitialized-issues)